# How to execute using path on AIX

Tags: shell, makefile, aix

When I try to execute a command within a folder :

```
$ omniidl
omniidl: No files specified. Use 'omniidl -u' for usage.
```

But, when I try to execute it using the path:

```
$ /usr/local/src/omniORB-4.1.4/build/omniidl
ksh: /usr/local/src/omniORB-4.1.4/build/omniidl:  not found.
```

What is happening? And should I change shells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, it appears you are missing some arguments to the `omniidl` command. In the second example, it does not appear you are using the correct full path; the command you executed in the first example is located somewhere other than `/usr/local/src/omniORB-4.1.4/build` (which sounds like a strange directory to appear in your `PATH` anyway). If you check the output of `which omniidl`, I suspect it will return a different absolute path for th executable.